# use of ELF file in embedded system?

Tags: c, compilation, linker, embedded, cross-compiling

The generation of ELF file (Executable and Linking Format) differs from a native c compiler to a cross compiler. What is use of ELF file in native C compiler and Cross compiler ?

Answer (score 2):

The job of a compiler is to convert ideally from higher to lower.  From C to assembly language from JAVA to bytecode, etc.  File in, file out.  Normally folks dont see that the compiler is usually (but not a hard and fast rule) putting out assembly language (text) which is then fed to the assembler THEN becomes elf or coff or whatever.   Doesnt matter you need a file format to store the information, when the information becomes binary (machine code) you need some file format, ANY file format.  The compiler authors/designers get to choose what file format(s) they want to support, elf is generic enough and works well, so not a bad choice.

Has absolutely nothing to do with the compiler it is just a file format that can be used to store the output of the assembler and linker.  You have to have some file format.

It may be possible that a toolchain chooses to have a different default file format depending on the combination of target or platform, for example gnu used on windows might make .EXE files the same gnu sources may choose elf as the default file format when compiled as a linux compiler.  And the natural extension to that is that the gnu tools may have a different default file format they use for other combinations of target processor and/or platform.

Elf in particular is a bit generic, certain markers and features may be used by combinations of target processor and platform, so you may see different flavors of elf.  Just look at using objcopy to intel hex format, the output changes depending on target processor type.

Comment: thank u very much...

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> ELF is a common standard file format for executables, object code,
>   shared libraries, and core dumps.

Whether you use a native or cross compiler has nothing to do with how an elf file is being generated. A cross compiler just takes into consideration that you are compiling for a different HW platform than the one you are currently using to compile on.